# Issue with pulling the data with EIA API with Python

Tags: python, pandas, api, python-requests

I am trying to pull some energy data using Energy Information Agency's API into a data frame. I wrote the following code:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

# Set the URL
url = "https://api.eia.gov/v2/electricity/rto/fuel-type-data/data/?frequency=hourly&data[0]=value&facets[respondent][]=ERCO&start=2018-07-01T00&end=2023-04-25T00&sort[0][column]=period&sort[0][direction]=desc&offset=0&length=5000&api_key=7xu8nejTweL67Zzzbsj2K4ngcGgTS828SqpfmSkD"

# Make the API request
response = requests.get(url)

# Extract the data from the response
data = response.json()["series"][0]["data"]

# Convert the data to a pandas dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["period", "value"])

# Print the dataframe
print(df)
```

However, I am getting this error:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[27], line 11
      8 response = requests.get(url)
     10 # Extract the data from the response
---> 11 data = response.json()["series"][0]["data"]
     13 # Convert the data to a pandas dataframe
     14 df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["period", "value"])

KeyError: 'series'
```

I checked that all libraries are correctly installed an imported, so I am confused about the source of the problem. Any idea what I am doing wrong? I'll greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: what do `response.json()` and `response.status_code` look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd

# Set the URL
url = "https://api.eia.gov/v2/electricity/rto/fuel-type-data/data/?frequency=hourly&data[0]=value&facets[respondent][]=ERCO&start=2018-07-01T00&end=2023-04-25T00&sort[0][column]=period&sort[0][direction]=desc&offset=0&length=5000&api_key=7xu8nejTweL67Zzzbsj2K4ngcGgTS828SqpfmSkD"

# Make the API request
data = requests.get(url).json()
df = pd.DataFrame(data['response']['data'])
print(df.head())
```

Prints:

```
          period respondent                              respondent-name fueltype    type-name  value    value-units
0  2023-04-25T00       ERCO  Electric Reliability Council of Texas, Inc.      WAT        Hydro    162  megawatthours
1  2023-04-25T00       ERCO  Electric Reliability Council of Texas, Inc.      COL         Coal   6398  megawatthours
2  2023-04-25T00       ERCO  Electric Reliability Council of Texas, Inc.      WND         Wind  10020  megawatthours
3  2023-04-25T00       ERCO  Electric Reliability Council of Texas, Inc.      OTH        Other     99  megawatthours
4  2023-04-25T00       ERCO  Electric Reliability Council of Texas, Inc.       NG  Natural gas  17616  megawatthours
```

---

If you want to have only `period`, `value` columns:

```
print(df[['period', 'value']].head())
```

Prints:

```
          period  value
0  2023-04-25T00    162
1  2023-04-25T00   6398
2  2023-04-25T00  10020
3  2023-04-25T00     99
4  2023-04-25T00  17616
```